# Select variable name on a double-click

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, when I double click on a variable like `initImage`, the IntelliJ only selects either "init" or "Image". 
How do I make IntelliJ select the whole variable/function name instead of a word in it?

Answer (score 2):

Check to see that you do not have the CamelHumps words setting turned on.

Under Editor->Smart Keys->Use CamelHumps words (or just search the settings for CamelHump).

Deselect it and that should resolve the issue.